# Multiple template parameters reference loop

Tags: c++, templates

I got two classes, a `B` class has a member `A1`, and the `A1` class has a reference member `B`, this is easy to write like this:

```
class B;

class A1 {
 public:
  A1(const B& b) : b_(b) {}
 private:
  const B& b_;  // a reference to B
};

class B {
 public:
  B(A1 a1) : a1_(a1) {}
 private:
  A1 a1_;  // a Type A1 member 
};
```

And then I need change class `B` to a template class, so the code should be like this:

```
template<typename T1>
class B;


class A1 {
 public:
  A1(const B<A1> &b) : b_(b) {};
 private:
  const B<A1> &b_; // a reference to B<A1>
};

template<typename T1>
class B {
 public:
  B(T1 t1) : t1_(t1){}
 private:
  T1 t1_; //a T1 type member
};
```

And suddenly we need a second member in `B`, so I changed the `B` to this:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class B {
 public:
  B(T1 t1, T2 t2) : t1_(t1), t2_(t2){}
 private:
  T1 t1_;
  T2 t2_;
};
```

This got a problem:

now if I'm a coder of `A`, the code below is illegal:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class B;


class A1 {
 public:
  A1(const B<A1> &b) : b_(b) {}; //wrong, need a second template argument
 private:
  const B<A1> &b_; // wrong, either
};
```

That means the coder must fill the second template argument which he may not know (or at least, may not care about). So I change the code to this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class B;

template <typename TB>
class A1 {
 public:
  explicit A1(const TB& b) : b_(b) {}
 private:
  const TB& b_;
};

template <typename TB>
class A2 {
 public:
  explicit A2(const TB& b) : b_(b) {}
 private:
  const TB& b_;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class B {
 public:
  B(T1 a1, T2 a2) : a1_(a1), a2_(a2) {}
 private:
  T1 a1_;
  T2 a2_;
};
```

This looks nice except I don't know how to make a `B` instance(like this:`B<A1<B<A1<...>,A2>, A2>`, it's recursively.)

The ideal design I'm looking forward to is that programmers for `A1` and `A2` simply do not need to know each other, and the programmer for `B` is simply add `A1` and `A2` more or less like this `B<A1, A2>`(or add some other stuff), and even if he add a `T3` parameter like `B<A1, A2, A3>, the code of`A1`and`A2` will not need to be changed.

So

1: If I insist in this syntax, does this mean I have to give up using template for `B`, instead use pointers?

2: If I insist in using template, does this mean the class `T1` and class `T2` must know each other?

3: Is there a third way by using template while `T1` and `T2` is independent? That is, no matter how many parameters I add to class `B`, the `A1` class does not need to change? Template template/CRTP/SFINAE, all of this seems not useful. As the `B` class is only a reference in class `A`, the `B` class is more like a interface rather than a certain class, this remind me of the C++ proposal "concept", can "concept" help in this case?

4: Is this a xy problem? That means I should not design my code pattern in this way?

Comment: Could you have a default argument value for `T2`?

Comment: Alternatively, you could rename `B` to something else, and make `template <typename T> using B = B_improved<T, whatever>;`.

Comment: Shouldn't you make A also a template class? Because if A stores an instance of B that means that using A is only possible if you know the second type of B.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat hi, can you show me some examples?  I can’t imagine how a default argument helps here

Comment: If you used e.g. `template <typename T1, typename T2 = int> class B;`, then `B<A1>` would no longer be a error.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don’t think this actually solved the problem... we will use some type more than the default eventually...

Comment: @BenjaminBihler I have update my question, make class `A` a template is easy, but I don't know how to initialize a class `B`, it will cause a recursive.

Comment: To me it sounds more like a design problem. I think class A should not "know" class B, rather it should reference some interface (abstract class) that is implemented by B and that is not generic.

Comment: @reavenisadesk Why? Make `A` a template class, make the constructor of `A` receive a template argument of type `T2` and pass it as second argument to the constructor of `B`. Either you do not know `T2` when initializing A. Then it is anyway a wrong decision to make `A` store an instance of `B`. Or you know `T2` when initializing `A`, then my proposal seems exactly right to me.

Comment: @o_weisman Yes, what you suggest is a typical run-time polymorphism, while in this case, all the class type is fixed on compiled time, so I'd like to find if there's a "template" way to do this.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler that is still a "independent" way, I think. If one day someone change the `B` class to 3 template parameters, all the code should be re-write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how one might do that.

```
// B doesn't know about A
template <class T1, class T2>
class B {};

// A doesn't know about B
template <template<class> class TB>
class A {
    using MyB = TB<A<TB>>;
};

template <class K>
    using Bint = B<K, int>;

int main() {
    A<Bint> abint;
}
```

Edit: If B has more than one template parameters, this can also be done, though a bit more complicated. One needs to tie all the template parameters in one class using some helpers. Here's an example. (I have renamed the classes for clarity).

```
// The top class parameterised by 3 bottom classes
template <class A1, class A2, class A3>
struct Top {};

// Three bottom classes parameterised by the top
template <template<class> class T> struct Bottom1 {};
template <template<class> class T> struct Bottom2 {};
template <template<class> class T> struct Bottom3 {};

// Until this point, none of the classes know about any other.
// Now tie them together with these helper definitions.

template <typename K>
using BundledTop = Top<typename K::A1, typename K::A2, typename K::A3>;

struct Bundle
{
    using A1 = Bottom1<BundledTop>;
    using A2 = Bottom2<BundledTop>;
    using A3 = Bottom3<BundledTop>;
};

using MyTop = BundledTop<Bundle>;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. What if I change the `int` to `A2`(a class which also has a reference to B, just like `A1`)? I think this solution does not completely solve the `T1` `T2` dependence problem...

Comment: @reavenisadesk Having a reference to B is nothing special, don't see a problem here. Do you mean B is parameterised by both A1 and A2, and both A1 and A2 are parameterised by B?

Comment: yes exactly, I add a `A2` class in the question, the `A2` class is basically the same as `A1`,  now `B` has `A1` and `A2` as members and both `A1` and `A2` has a reference to `B`, this is the "independent" problem I'm getting stuck with.

Comment: This is a complex structure, I think it should be doable but is it worth the effort?

Comment: Like @Benjamin Bihler said, my work is more like a tree and leaves syntax, except that this tree is fixed on compile time. I can give up the template and write the certain code each time, but I think it's a little annoying.

Comment: This design is really elegant, while I changed the `template <template<class> class T> struct Bottom1 {};` to `template <template<class> class T, typename E> struct Bottom1 {};` to avoid `Bundle` class showing in the `Bottom` class, do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: @reavenisadesk If it works, why not. The design can be improved, it's just a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your answer 4 is this right one: this seems as being a flawed design. I cannot prove that but I would like to give you an example.

I have implemented something similar to your code when I have been implementing bounding volume hierarchies. You could think of `B` as a branch class and `A` as a leave class of the tree (that is not completely correct, but should give an idea). Every branch has to contain its leaves, therefore `B` stores instances of `A`. But it is also nice to go back from a leave to its branch, therefore `A` should store a reference to `B`. You could decide to make your bounding volume hierarchy store arbitrary content (triangle, quads, polygons), therefore the item type should be a template parameter. Also you might decide to make the maximum leave number of each branch a template parameter of `B`.

But why should the branch class be able to store leaves that are made for arbitrary branches (because the `B` type is a template parameter of `A`)? If `B` stores instances of `A`, then I cannot think of any reason for making the `B` type a template parameter of `A`.

So probably you are too general here and should look for another design.

I am looking forward to your comments.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. So at last, which way did you choose? Give up the general design to write certain code? Or stick the general design by using pointers and run-time polymorphism?

Comment: I would give up the general design. If you have a compelling reason for being so general, please share it. But remember that if you try to write absolutely general software you will always end up writing an operating system.