# How to understand syntax TB<A1<TB>> and how this code works to avoid infinite recursion?

Tags: c++, templates

I got an example code as below:

```
#include <iostream>
template<class T1>
class B {
 public:
  B() : t1_(*this) {}
  void Test() {
    t1_.Test();
  }
  void Print() const {
    std::cout << "test\n";
  }
 private:
  T1 t1_;
};

template<template<class> class TB>
class A1 {
 public:
  explicit A1(const TB<A1<TB>> &b) : b_(b) {}
  void Test() {
    b_.Print();
  }
 private:
  const TB<A1<TB>> &b_;
};

int main() {
  B<A1<B>> bt;
  bt.Test();
}
```

This is insight by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53759168/2269707), this code make sure a class `B` has a member `A1` and the `A1` has a reference of `B`.

Although this code works, I really don't know how it works, especially the code  `const TB<A1<TB>> &b_;`. Since the `TB` is a template template parameter, The `TB<...>` is a specialization of `TB`, which parameter is `A1<TB>`, right? Then what does the second `TB` in `TB<A1<TB>>` mean? If the second `TB` is a template, why there's no parameter?

As Matthieu Brucher mentioned, this code is indeed used to avoid an infinite recursion. Since I'm not fully understand how this code works, can any body explain how a compiler do to make this code work? Or, what should this code look like after it is being compiled?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher As far as I can see, this is not an instance of CRTP.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher isn't CRTP used for static polymorphism? There's no static_cast here. Can you explain more?

Comment: My bad, I made a mistake.

Comment: Note that `BT` is a distraction. You can just as easily write `B<A1<B>>` directly

Comment: @Caleth yes your are right, the origin code is used BT for something else, I think I shoud edit the question to make it simple to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The second `TB` doesn't have a parameter because of `A1` declaration:

```
template<template<class> class TB>
class A1;
```

This says that `A1` takes one template argument, and the parameter itself takes an unspecified template argument. `A1` will do whatever it pleases with this template argument, but it must not be given when declaring `A1`, and this breaks the infinite recursion that would arise without this facility.

So for instance, you can write:

```
A1<TB> foo;
```

You can also write:

```
A1<std::vector> foo(std::vector<A1<std::vector>>()); // UB because of b storage, but it's the example
```

Comment: Note that `A1<std::vector>` is not valid pre-C++17 as `std::vector` has extra default parameter (Allocator).

Comment: @Jarod42 indeed, I used `-std=c++17 -O3 -pedantic`. But it was an example, nothing more.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher thanks for answering, can you tell me more how this syntax can avoid the infinite recursion?

Comment: The way `A1` is declared doesn't require `B` to be fully specified. It doesn't require a type, but a template, as Jarod explained it. Without the `template<class>`, you would need to specify the template argument for `TB`, so that breaks the recursion.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, here's what confused me, if the declaration of `A1` doesn't require `B` to be fully specified, how compiler knows the member `b_` in `const TB<A1<TB>> &b_;` is exactly the type I wondered? That is to say, how `A1` knows for sure his member `b_` has a member which type is `A1` while not some other type?

Comment: It's the "recursion" that makes it possible. `TB<A1<B>>` is a fully specified type, and inside `A1`, this type is also fully specified because `TB` is a template class that can be defined as we expect. I agree it's not natural at the first sight, I would suggest to sleep on it, often my brain lets me understand things after some sleep!

Comment: `TB<A1<TB>>` would be know when instantiating the template (so in main, once both A and B are complete).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher "`TB<A1<TB>>` is a fully specified type" @Jarod42 "`TB<A1<TB>>` would be know when instantiating the template" are clues for me, I'll take you advise and let my brain get relaxed for a while;)

Answer (score 2):

`B` expects a type, whereas `A1` expects a template.

So you may have `B<int>` but not `A1<int>`.
Similar way, you may have `A1<B>` but not `B<B>`.

Back to

```
template<template <class > class TB> class A1;
```

`TB` is a template, not a type, but `TB<int>` is a type.

so for `TB<A1<TB>>`,

- (inner) `TB` is a template.
- `A1<TB>` is a type.
- `TB< T2 >` is a type (with `T2` = `A1<TB>`).

Comment: Thanks for answering, does this mean by saying "A1<TB> is a type", the compiler do not care about what `A1<TB>` really looks like at that moment? Then how exactly the compiler know the format(or specialization? or how it looks like?) of `A1<TB>`?

Comment: Don't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: Probably because I'm still not fully understand how this works, is there any document to illustrate how compiler deal with this code?

Answer (score 0):

As inspired by Matthieu Brucher and Jarod42, I will try to use the view of a compiler to explain this, **correct me if I'm wrong.**

As Jarod42 mentioned:

> (inner) TB is a template.
>
> A1< TB > is a type.
>
> TB< T2 > is a type (with T2 = A1)

and by the fact that template will instantiate when it is used, the line `B<A1<B>> bt;` is the place where the template fall into certain type.
So `A1<B>` is a type, let's make the real class named A1_IMPL, that is `A1<B>--A1_IMPL`, `B<A1<B>>` is a type, let make the class named B_IMPL, that is `B<A1<B>>--B<A1_IMPL>--B_IMPL`. So the B_IMPL looks like this:

```
class B_IMPL {
 public:
  B_IMPL() : t1_(*this) {}
  void Test() {
    t1_.Test();
  }
  void Print() const {
    std::cout << "test\n";
  }
 private:
  A1_IMPL t1_;
};
```

A1 will look like this:

```
class A1_IMPL {
 public:
  explicit A1_IMPL(const B<A1<B>> &b) : b_(b) {}
  void Test() {
    b_.Print();
  }
 private:
  const B<A1<B>> &b_;
};
```

that's not finished, since `A1<B>--A1_IMPL`,`B<A1<B>>--B<A1_IMPL>--B_IMPL`, the final A1_IMPL will looks like this:

```
class A1_IMPL {
 public:
  explicit A1_IMPL(const B_IMPL &b) : b_(b) {}
  void Test() {
    b_.Print();
  }
 private:
  const B_IMPL &b_;
};
```

there's no template any more.